# how to record audio file in browser except Recorder.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, audio-recording

i want to record audio file in browser except recorder.cs , why because if i use recorder.js means it is not working in Google chrome browser after deploying application in IIS webserver .

Comment: How about web audio recorder js? https://github.com/higuma/web-audio-recorder-js

Answer (score 1):

> navigator.getUserMedia() API

is what you need.

With that API you can record audio and video just by using `html` and `javascript`. The library is widely used to record video/audio or take snapshots.

I don't want to copy and paste the code from other websites so, all the code that you will need you can find under the links below.

- [simpl.info](https://simpl.info)
- [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia)

**Support:**
[image]